# Trim end of string by pattern (regex?)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, trim

I'm not so good at regex..

Looking for a way to trim the end of a string, if the end is:

**A space followed by ONE character (can be any character)**

Is preg_replace() the thing for that, or is there an easier and faster way?

The trimming will only happen once in the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just a space do this. And yes preg_replace is the way to go.

```
$string = preg_replace('/ .$/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
$foo = 'hello w';
$bar = preg_replace('/\s\S\z/', '', $foo);
```

(assuming "any character" means "any non-space character"). [More on "\" stuff.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: Works fine ;) But I'm going with '/ .$/' as it's easier to understand and look at, without the backslashes etc.

Comment: @mowgli: well, "backslashes" are there for a reason, and this is not because I think they look nicer.